# Tomcat server won't start if my servlet references another project

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat9

I currently have 2 java projects that should be working together. The first project, Controllers, contains classes that should establish a connection to my database and communicate with it.

The second project is a dynamic web project with a servlet and 2 jsps(LoginPage and Welcomepage). The servlet uses the objects in the controller project to connect to the database, verify that a user's username and password are correct, and send them to a welcome screen.

Here's where it gets weird. As soon as I attempt to declare an object defined in my cotrollers project, my server refuses to start. It gives no error other than "Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start." I have verified that my server works, I have checked that the build path is configured correctly, I have even commented out all the code in the controller object being defined. It's as if the mere act of declaring an object from another project causes the error, but I don't see how that would prevent the server from starting.

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: Read the log. It is probably going to tell you that it cannot find the class you're trying to use. Remember, your IDE might know where it is in terms of a class path, but your server doesn't. If this is during startup when class loading takes place, make sure your controller .jar file is in the lib directory of tomcat.

Comment: another note. `lib` directory is frowned on. Package it in your /WEB-INF/lib

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: why two projects? why not put all of it in one dynamic web project?

Comment: I thought specifying the controller project in the build path meant that I wouldn't need the .jar file, at least during development? And I put them in separate files because its for school and I hope to use the same controller files for several of my projects.